# What does it mean at the top a .cgi file "#!/usr/bin/env php" versus "#!/usr/bin/php"?

Tags: cgi, webserver

I usually see

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

at the top of a CGI file.  How is a

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

different from the first 2 lines?  They work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Shebangs, the `#!/usr/bin/sh` part of the script, require an absolute path to the interpreter. Because there is no standard path for some interpreters some scripts use `#!/usr/bin/env interpreter` to launch the correct interpreter.

Comment: env as in bash or csh or sh?  How does it decide?

Comment: It'll use whatever SHELL is set to for the user invoking /usr/bin/env, but I'm not sure how it's relevant: invoke the intrepreter you want with "/usr/bin/env interpreter". If you want to use bash, use "/usr/bin/env bash".

Comment: can't `bash` set PATH and `sh` set PATH that are totally different?  And then php refers to php5 in `bash` and refers to php4 in `sh`

Comment: Ah, yes. It should use the environment variables for the shell specified in /etc/passwd, but I'm not exactly sure how it works for non-standard shells like /dev/null or /bin/false. If you invoke env manually, it'll use the environment variables for whatever shell you're currently in.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented on the Wikipedia page for [env](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env). It basically runs the command without modifying existing environment variables.